# Converting C++ Palindrome function to MIPS

Tags: c++, assembly, mips

I'm trying to convert a function I wrote in `C++` into `MIPS`. The function tests whether a char array is a palindrome, a string that is symmetric in its characters (ex: "heeh" and "gtrertg" are palindromes, "hey" is not). In `MIPS`, the string is being passed through `$a0` and the return value should be passed in `$v0`. This is my `C++` code:

```
 #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

    int palindrome(char s[])
    {
            int j;
            j = 0;
            int i;
            i = -1;
            //finding length of string...
            while(s[i+1] != '\0')
            {
                    i++;
            }
            //while the two opposite chars are equal...
            while(s[j] == s[i])
            {
                    //if the chars are at the same index...
                    if(i == j)
                    {
                            //palindrome
                            return 1;
                    }
                    //if the left index passes the right index...
                    if(j > i)
                    {
                            //palindrome
                            return 1;
                    }
                    //increment left index
                    j++;
                    //decrement right index
                    i--;
            }
            //not palindrome
            return 0;
    }
```

I have tested my `C++` code and it works just fine. This is my `MIPS` code:

```
#$a0 contains the address of the string
.data

.text

.globl palindrome

palindrome:
    li        $t0, 0            #j = 0
    li        $t1, -1           #i = -1
    addi      $t2, $a0, 0       #a[0]
L1:     
    addi      $t2, $t2, 1       #a[i + 1]
    addi      $t1, $t1, 1       #i++
    bne       $t2, $zero, L1        #exit loop when '\0' is found
    add       $t2, $a0, $t0     #a[j]
    add       $t3, $a0, $t1     #a[i]
L2A:
    bne       $t1, $t0, If2     #if i does not equal j jump to next if
    j         Return1           #jump to Return1 label                  
If2:        
    ble       $t1, $t0, L2B     #if j<= i, skip if statement
    j         Return1           #jump to Return1 label  
L2B:
    addi      $t0, $t0, 1       #j++
    addi      $t1, $t1, -1      #i--
    beq       $t2, $t3, L2A     #exit loop when a[j] != a[i]
Return1:
    addi      $v0, $zero, 1     #return 1
    j         Exit
Return0:
    addi      $v0, $zero, 0     #return 0
    j         Exit
Exit:
    jr        $ra           #return
```

I'm getting an error in my first loop when determining the size of the string when checking for the `\0` character. Can someone help? Also, I have to convert the characters of the string into the same case. Would I need another loop in the beginning to go and check for their int ASCII representation and increment or decrement it by a certain number depending on the case? If you see any other mistakes, including conventional mistakes, please point them out. The file that tests the palindrome file has been error checked and works as it should.

Comment: I think you should *access the array* via `lb` instruction.

Comment: Your `L1` loop never reads anything from `a`. What it compares against `$zero` is an _address_ (i.e. `&(a[i])` in C). The address is unlikely to equal zero.

Comment: why don't you implement this as passing half the string into the .stack and then compare the register with the stack operands.

Comment: @Michael How would I compare each character to `\0`? A tutor told me that its ASCII value is 0, so that's what I tried to look for in the string. And this was the first implementation I thought of @Danyal